# In this PHP, where do I put the category ID in order to return blog entries of a category?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

This comes from a PHP script in a theme of WordPress.  I need to return blog entries with category that has an ID of 20.

```
<?php /* make a new query for grid items (in single page) */
    $new_query_arg = 'paged='.$paged;

    // use this code if you want filter items by category.
    $arr_catID = array();
    foreach( get_the_category() as $cat) $arr_catID[] = $cat->cat_ID;
    if ( count($arr_catID) ) $new_query_arg .= '&cat=' . join(',', $arr_catID);

    query_posts($new_query_arg);
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only display entries with category ID 20, then replace all the code with:

```
query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&cat=20');
```

Comment: I guess we could reduce it even to one line. The variable initialization is pretty pointless.

Comment: Thanks!  It also works with array(20), but I am guessing all that extra stuff was not necessary.